# Bamboo build failing with Internal server error

Tags: maven-3, bamboo

We are using Bamboo to deploy an application using Maven which is connecting to the Weblogic server. We are getting the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal ***.maven-plugins:deploy-maven-plugin:1.0.27:deploy-request (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Could not execute request: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://****/wdb-ctx-svc/service/deploy-log
```

Even though bamboo build fails the deployment continues in the background and is successful. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two points : Firstly, if your build is failing, your deployment should not trigger ideally. You can add a trigger to your deployment , that is , to run it only after successful build. Secondly is your web-logic server reachable ? I mean are you able to ping it or telnet to it ? I guess more of a network issue .